# Error attempting to create test data in @TestSetup

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

This Trigger sends an email alert when an Account creates 8 cases within a 7 day period.  If any of 3 specific fields is equal to `'LIVE - CLOSED PROJECT'` the email is sent to a Global Email address.  If none of the three fields have that value, the email is sent to 2 other email addresses in the Else block.

When I use two different personal email address for testing the email is sent no problem through the if/else statement.

My issue is in the Test Class with Assert Equals.  I know the IF statement send 1 email and the Else Block sends 2.  My assertEquals checks continue to return fail and shows that 0 email invocations were sent.
All tests Pass in the Tests tab, and show a green check if I comment out the assert.Equals line.

What am I missing?

```
trigger CaseHandlerCountAlert on Case (after insert) {

//Case trigger that will send email alert when 8 cases are created within 7 days.
String messageToSend;
List <String> ListOfMessages = new List <String>();
Set <Id> AcctIds = new Set <Id>();
String messageBody;

List < AggregateResult > AggregateResultList = [SELECT AccountId, Account.Name name, COUNT(Id) co
                                                FROM Case
                                                WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:7 AND Id IN :Trigger.New
                                                GROUP BY AccountId, Account.Name
                                                HAVING COUNT(Id) >= 8
                                               ];

Map < Id, String > accountIdEmailmessageMap = new Map < Id, String > ();

for (AggregateResult aggr: AggregateResultList) {
    String messageToSend = 'Account name: ' + aggr.get('name') +
        ' has ' + (Integer) aggr.get('co') +
        ' cases opened in the last 8 days.';
    Id accId = (Id) aggr.get('AccountId');
    accountIdEmailmessageMap.put(accId, messageToSend);
    AcctIds.add(accId);
}


List < Case > caseList = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.Name, Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.Implementation_status__c,
                          Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.PM_Implementation_Status__c,
                          Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.RCM_Implementation_Status__c,
                          Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.Resource_Coordinator_Email__c,
                          Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.Client_Advisor_Email__c                      
                          FROM Case
                          WHERE AccountId IN: AcctIds];

List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lstASingleEmailMessage = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lstBSingleEmailMessage = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

for (Case cl: caseList) {

    if (cl.Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.Implementation_status__c == 'Live - Closed Project' ||
        cl.Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.PM_Implementation_Status__c == 'Live - Closed Project' ||
        cl.Parent_Project_If_Applicable__r.RCM_Implementation_Status__c == 'Live - Closed Project') {

            String messageBody = accountIdEmailmessageMap.get(cl.AccountId);

            List<String> emailaddr = new List<String>();
            emailaddr.add('CustomerSuccessManagers@test.com');  

            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('Support');
            mail.setToAddresses(emailaddr);   
            mail.Subject = 'Multiple cases created alert message';
            mail.setPlainTextBody(messageBody);
            lstASingleEmailMessage.add(mail);




        }else{
            String messageBody = accountIdEmailmessageMap.get(cl.AccountId);        

            List<String> emailAdds = new List<String>();
          //  emailAdds.add(cl.Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.Resource_Coordinator_Email__c);
            emailAdds.add('cl.Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.Client_Advisor_Email__c'); 

            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage amail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            amail.SetSenderDisplayName('Support');
            amail.setToAddresses(emailAdds);
            amail.Subject = 'Multiple cases created alert message';
            amail.setPlainTextBody(messageBody);
            lstBSingleEmailMessage.add(amail);
            System.debug('messageBody: ' + messageBody);
            System.debug('email message: ' + amail);

        }  
}
Messaging.SendEmailResult[] r = Messaging.sendEmail(lstASingleEmailMessage);
Messaging.SendEmailResult[] rb = Messaging.sendEmail(lstBSingleEmailMessage);
}
```

Test Class:

```
    @isTest
private class TestCaseHandlerAlert {

    @isTest static void setup(){
        Account a = new Account();
            //a.RecordTypeId = '01230000000v58OAAQ';
            a.name = 'testacct21';

  // Create parent Project

 Milestone1_Project__c project = new Milestone1_Project__c();
        //project.RecordTypeId = '01214000001RYp2AAG';
        project.Name = 'triggertest12';
        project.RCM_Implementation_Status__c = 'LIVE - CLOSED PROJECT';
        project.PM_Implementation_Status__c = 'LIVE - CLOSED PROJECT';
        project.Implementation_Status__c = 'LIVE - CLOSED PROJECT';

     //Insert Account
    insert a;

    //Insert Project
    insert project;

    //Create 10 Cases associated with Project

    List<Case> casesToInsert = new List<Case>();

    for (Integer i=1; i<12; i++){

    Case c = new Case();
        c.AccountId = a.id;
    //  c.RecordTypeId = '01214000001RYp7AAG';
        c.Origin = 'Phone';
        c.Impact__c = 'Low';
        c.Severity__c = 'Minor';
        c.Type = 'Bridge';
        c.Parent_Project_if_applicable__c = project.id;

        casesToInsert.add(c);
    }          
      insert casesToInsert;        
    }

    @isTest static void PassSendEmailIfBlock (){
        // Set 3/3 fields to 'Live - Closed Project' Send to Global Email Address
        List<Case> testCases = [SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Account.Name='testacct21' LIMIT 8];

      Test.startTest();
        insert testCases;
       // System.assertEquals(1, Limits.getEmailInvocations());
       System.debug(Limits.getEmailInvocations());
      Test.stopTest();
    }    

    @isTest static void PassRCMimpIfBlock (){
        // Set field number 1/3 to 'Live - Closed Project' Send to Global Email Address
        List<Case> testCases = [SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Account.Name='testacct21' LIMIT 8];
        List<Case> insertCases = new List<Case>();   
            for(Case cas :testCases){
                cas.Parent_Project_If_Applicable__r.PM_Implementation_Status__c = null;
                cas.Parent_Project_If_Applicable__r.Implementation_Status__c = null;
                insertCases.add(cas);
            }

      Test.startTest();
        insert insertCases;
      //  System.assertEquals(1, Limits.getEmailInvocations());
            System.debug(Limits.getEmailInvocations());
      Test.stopTest();
    }

    @isTest static void PassPMimpIfBlock (){
        // Set field number 2/3 to 'Live - Closed Project' Send to Global Email Address
        List<Case> testCases = [SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Account.Name='testacct21' LIMIT 8];
        List<Case> insertCases = new List<Case>();   
            for(Case cas :testCases ){
                cas.Parent_Project_If_Applicable__r.RCM_Implementation_Status__c = null;
                cas.Parent_Project_If_Applicable__r.Implementation_Status__c = null;
                insertCases.add(cas);
            }

      Test.startTest();
        insert insertCases;
      //  System.assertEquals(1, Limits.getEmailInvocations());
      System.debug(Limits.getEmailInvocations());
      Test.stopTest();
    }

    @isTest static void PassImpIfBlock (){
        // Set field number 3/3 to 'Live - Closed Project' Send to Global Email Address
        List<Case> testCases = [SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Account.Name='testacct21' LIMIT 8];
        List<Case> insertCases = new List<Case>();   
            for(Case cas :testCases ){
                cas.Parent_Project_If_Applicable__r.RCM_Implementation_Status__c = null;
                cas.Parent_Project_If_Applicable__r.PM_Implementation_Status__c = null;
                insertCases.add(cas);
            }

      Test.startTest();
        insert insertCases;
      //  System.assertEquals(1, Limits.getEmailInvocations());
            System.debug(Limits.getEmailInvocations());
      Test.stopTest();
    }

@isTest static void DontSendIfBlock (){
        // Do not send, not enough Cases need 8 
        List<Case> testCases = [SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Account.Name='testacct21' LIMIT 5];
        List<Case> insertCases = new List<Case>();   

      Test.startTest();
        insert insertCases;
    //  System.assertEquals(0, Limits.getEmailInvocations());
        System.debug(Limits.getEmailInvocations());
      Test.stopTest();
    }

@isTest static void SendToElseBlock (){
        // Sends Email to Advisor and Coordinator
        List<Case> testCases = [SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Account.Name='testacct21' LIMIT 8];
        List<Case> insertCases = new List<Case>();  
        for(Case cas :testCases ){
                cas.Parent_Project_If_Applicable__r.RCM_Implementation_Status__c = null;
                cas.Parent_Project_If_Applicable__r.Implementation_Status__c = null;
                cas.Parent_Project_If_Applicable__r.PM_Implementation_Status__c = null;

                insertCases.add(cas);
            } 

      Test.startTest();
        insert insertCases;
    //  System.assertEquals(2, Limits.getEmailInvocations());
        System.debug(Limits.getEmailInvocations());
      Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to check the emails after your test is done. Add something like this on your asserts.

We just want to use a SOQL on the EmailMessage and get them by the email subject.

```
// When
Test.startTest();
// Your test 
Test.stopTest();

// Then
List<EmailMessage> newMails = [SELECT Id, Subject FROM EmailMessage];
System.assert(!newMails.isEmpty(), 'No mails sent');
System.assertEquals('YUOR EMAIL SUBJECT', newMails.get(0).Subject, 'Mail subject not set correctly');
```

This way is also a good approach to test if your emails are sent.

Comment: this will not work if the org does not have email deliverability = all (which is not the default for a sandbox). [An approach I use involves using the Unit Of Work pattern and mocking](http://cropredysfdc.com/2017/10/23/apexmocks-and-email/)